# how to code multiple values of an indicator into new custom indicator?(MQL5)

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

Let's use MACD as an example. It has 2-3 values(1st for the MACD line, 2nd for the signal line, and 3rd if it has a histogram).

I'm trying to incorporate those values into a new indicator. I figured I would need multiple buffers and SetIndexBuffer indicator calculations for the MACD indicator. I'm having a difficult time figuring it out or finding an answer on the web.

Need some help with all of the ins and outs.

Thanks in advance!